# Project with path '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android' could not be found in project ':app'

Tags: react-native

After updating react-native version 0.60.3 to 0.60.4, I am not able to build apk every time run the "react-native run-android" command an error message appears

```
   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   * Where:
   Build file 'C:\Front_End\android\app\build.gradle' line: 161

   * What went wrong:
   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
   > Project with path '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android' 
   could not be found in project ':app'.
```

I have checked inside node_modules this module is present.

Comment: Do you have `react-native-code-push` file?

Comment: Remove the node modules and then again install the node modules by the following command  `npm i`  and see if the error is gone or not.

Comment: Yes i have react-native-code-push in node_modules folder. Also i have deleted the node_modules folder and re-install all modules. But the error is still persist.